# imprimir variavel Java script dentro do HTML

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

como imprimo a váriavel click dentro do Html

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(".j_requerimento").click(function(){
     var click = 1;
     $(".j_label_requerimento").append("<span>IMPRIMIR AQUI A VARIAVEL CLICK</span>");});
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que você escreveu, basta fazer uma pequena alteração:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".j_requerimento").click(function(){
     var click = 1;
     $(".j_label_requerimento").append(`<span>${click}</span>`);});
</script>
```

Nesse caso, usamos as [Template Strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) do ES6. Porém, isso não é suportado em todos os navegadores. Logo, outra opção é usar:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".j_requerimento").click(function(){
     var click = 1;
     $(".j_label_requerimento").append("<span>" + click + "</span>");});
</script>
```

Comment: muito obrigado resolveu meu problema !!